# I get NPM ERR when I try to install strapi

Tags: npm, npm-install, strapi, npx

I tried to install strapi with npx create-strapi-app backend, but an error keep appearing , I couldn't solve the problem or found any solution anywhere, I don't know what I'm doing wrong exaclty
Here is the code error I'm getting :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As the error says, there isn't a Visual Studio installation to use. Install Visual Studio and it should work. Also, please post errors as **text** not images.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Comment: Already seen this error, try installing build tools mentioned in link from previous comment